# Java - nested for loop and StringBuilder

Tags: java, for-loop, stringbuilder

```
public void insertThis(List<String> dbFields){
    StringBuilder implode = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 1;
    for(String nFields : dbFields){
        implode.append(nFields);
        implode.append(",");
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(implode.toString());
}
```

the output of this code is:

```
emp_id,emp_lname,emp_fname,
```

Can someone please help me how to make the output like this?

```
emp_id,emp_lname,emp_fname
```

I want an output that there will be no comma on the last, just in between of the emp_id, emp_lname and emp_fname on my code, i would greatly appreciate your help for me.

Comment: Sorry Jr. but you deserve -1 for patching your issue instead of fixing it.

Comment: @alfasin it's alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `String.LastIndexOf(char a)` method.

Find out index of the last comma.

Using that index make use of `String.subString(index)` method.

FOr e.g.

```
String a="emp_id,emp_lname,emp_fname,";
System.out.println( a.substring(0,a.lastIndexOf(",")));
```

Output-

```
emp_id,emp_lname,emp_fname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils`:

```
StringUtils.join(dbFields, ",")
```

If you insist on using the code above, add the following line:

```
if(index < lst.size())
```

before:

```
implode.append(",");
```

Comment: I think you need to specify where to find StringUtils for this guy ;)

Comment: StringUtils.join(dbFields, ","); is not functioning on me the join has a red underline.

Comment: @Jr.Programmer and what does the red line says ? (compilation error due to missing/incorrect `import` ?)

Comment: -1 for suggesting to use an internal undocumented API (that Oracle could delete at any time)

Comment: @immibis peace brother, I wish you all the best! (by the way - it would be nice of you if you'd post a link to the source that suggests that Oracle is going to delete it!)

Comment: Thanks for the help man @alfasin, but it seems it's complicated for me as an intermediate. I found a subtring answer thanks, maybe i would the research next time about this thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you :

```
 for(String nFields : dbFields){
        implode.append(nFields);
        if(index != dbFields.size())
         implode.append(",");
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't append the comma after each record, you add it before a new record, e.g.

```
for(...) {
    if (!implode.toString().isEmpty())
        implode.append(",");
    implode.append(nFields);
}
```